# Remove date columns with no data in ggplot2 geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to hide columns with no data in ggplot2.  Here is a reproducible example using the nycflights13 library:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

small_data <- flights %>%
  mutate(date = lubridate::make_date(year, month, day)) %>%
  filter(year == 2013, 
         month ==3)

ggplot(small_data) +
  geom_bar(aes(date)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d - %b", date_breaks = "1 day") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 65, hjust = 1))
```

[image: geom_bar with additional bars]

As yopu can see, although I have only selected data for march, I have column titles for 28 Feb and 01 April.

I have tried the following:

[hide missing dates from x-axis ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30880877/hide-missing-dates-from-x-axis-ggplot2) (the solution no longer works)

setting `(date_)breaks = levels(factor(small_data$date))`

Please help me hide the unnecessary bars.

Comment: The option expand=c(0,0) adjust the x scale so it doesn't show unnecesary dates. Add "scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d - %b", date_breaks = "1 day", expand=c(0,0))"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

or we could set `scale_x_date(..., expand = c(0,0))`:

```
ggplot(small_data) +
    geom_bar(aes(date)) +
    scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d - %b", date_breaks = "1 day",
                 expand = c(0,0)) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 65, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

We can specify the date breaks in the `breaks` argument (not in `date_breaks`).

```
ggplot(small_data) +
  geom_bar(aes(date)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d - %b", 
               breaks = seq(min(small_data$date), max(small_data$date), by = 1)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 65, hjust = 1))
```