# Remove extra month in R geom_bar

Tags: r, dplyr, geom-bar

I added a 'month_year' column to my data.frame using `lubridate::floor_date`. However, now when I plot my geom_bar, I get an extra month at each end.

How do I remove the extra months?

I have tried `seq(as.Date)`, but I get the error:

> Error in parse_period_unit(unit) :    Cannot't parse heterogenuous or
> fractional units larger than one minute.

I appreciate your help.

The Data:

```
structure(list(month_year = structure(c(18506, 18506, 18536, 
18536, 18567, 18567, 18597, 18597, 18628, 18628, 18659, 18659, 
18687, 18687, 18718, 18718, 18748, 18748, 18779, 18779, 18809, 
18809, 18840, 18840, 18871, 18871), class = "Date"), member_casual = c("casual", 
"member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member", 
"casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual", 
"member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member", 
"casual", "member", "casual", "member"), n = c(212109L, 284005L, 
121479L, 215338L, 72497L, 149370L, 24403L, 89168L, 14590L, 68726L, 
8517L, 34296L, 74904L, 129820L, 118822L, 177325L, 213536L, 233461L, 
299050L, 303515L, 364569L, 321727L, 337787L, 331900L, 289944L, 
327225L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -26L), groups = structure(list(month_year = structure(c(18506, 
18506, 18536, 18536, 18567, 18567, 18597, 18597, 18628, 18628, 
18659, 18659, 18687, 18687, 18718, 18718, 18748, 18748, 18779, 
18779, 18809, 18809, 18840, 18840, 18871, 18871), class = "Date"), 
    member_casual = c("casual", "member", "casual", "member", 
    "casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member", 
    "casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member", 
    "casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member", 
    "casual", "member", "casual", "member"), .rows = structure(list(
        1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
        14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
        25L, 26L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -26L), .drop = TRUE))
```

The code:

```
monthly_riders %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= month_year, y = n, fill=member_casual)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90), legend.title = element_blank())+
  labs(title = "Total Monthly Riders")+
  xlab("")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma,name = "Riders", expand = c(0,0))+
  scale_x_date(date_labels="%b %y", date_breaks = "1 month")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `expand=expansion(0,0)`:

```r
monthly_riders %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= month_year, y = n, fill=member_casual)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90), legend.title = element_blank())+
  labs(title = "Total Monthly Riders")+
  xlab("")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma,name = "Riders", expand = c(0,0))+
  scale_x_date(date_labels="%b %y", date_breaks = "1 month", expand = expansion(0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why that happens, or where I can go to find out?

Comment: R graphics (both base and `ggplot2`) normally expand axes so that all elements (layers, points, etc) are fully-contained within the plot region.

Comment: Thank you. This will help tidy up my charts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `limits` function:

`

```
monthly_riders %>% ggplot(aes(x= month_year, y = n, fill=member_casual)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90), legend.title = element_blank())+
  labs(title = "Total Monthly Riders")+
  xlab("")+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Riders", expand = c(0,0))+
  scale_x_date(date_labels="%b %y", date_breaks = "1 month", limits=as.Date(c("2020-09-01","2021-09-01")))
```

`

Note that I removed the "labels = comma," as it was giving me an error.

Comment: When I tried to use ```limits``` both the Septembers only had one set of data instead of two.

Comment: Using expand=c(0,0) as per this answer might work better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037746/remove-date-columns-with-no-data-in-ggplot2-geom-bar (remove the limits statement)

I didn't see the answer above, which has the same idea.